# What is the best way to add days to the date in PHP?

Tags: php, date

I have a date value with time. (27/4/2014 18:00:00)

In addition to it, I have a string that consists of days/hours/mins. (10/7/0).

In the end, I need to sum the two values making one date.

In this example, the sum of the values is 37/4/2014 28:7:00.

So the desired result would be 8/5/2014 4:7:00. What is the best way to get this result in PHP??

Comment: `strtotime("+1 day", strtotime("date string"))` ?

Comment: Smar's comment is a good approach, but I would strongly recommend working with actual `DateTime` objects instead of string representations. Create a `DateTime` from the start date, `modify()` or `add()` the needed timespan, and only convert it to string when you need it.

Comment: When you add 10 hours, 7 minutes to `27/4/2014 18:00:00`, shouldn't it become `28/4/2014 04:00:00` instead? As `28:7:00` isn't a valid time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
function($date, $addon)
{
    $date1 = strtotime($date);

    $explode = explode('/', $addon);
    $date2 = ($explode[0]*86400) + ($explode[1]*3600) + ($explode[2]*60);

    return date('j/n/Y H:i:s', ($date1+$date2));
}
```

Comment: There is no `strtodate()` function. You mean `strtotime()`?

Comment: Yes did a typo. Thanks :)

Comment: Date math should be done with actual date concepts (hours, days, months, etc.), not with hardcoded seconds. Your approach will break on Daylight Savings and leap seconds. (Also, your code is using `$explode[0]` twice.)

Answer (score 0):

I'd convert them to timestamps then add them and convert them back:

```
$time = strtotime($time1) + strtotime($time2);

echo date('m/d/Y h:i:s a', $time);
```

Comment: In this case, `$time2` is a timespan/time interval, not a proper date. Treating it as a date is incorrect, and adding two *dates* together is logically incorrect (what does it mean to add "1990 April 15th" to "2004 June 3rd"?).

Comment: I agree that it doesn't make much sense logically. However, this approach could work if you either added the period in seconds (ie. 24 * 60 * 60 to advance a day) or used a date offset from 1/1/70.